# Entity Framework, The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use custom framework for EF but I am having a problem that I dont understand. The error is below. It seems very obvious but I am not sure how to fix it

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

Parameter name: path

I am calling this function and it throws the exception above.

```
_menuRepository.GetAll(d => d.DateToDisplay <= DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(d=>d.Id).Take(100).ToList();
```

and GetAll() function is like below.

```
public virtual IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    List<T> list;
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

        //Apply eager loading
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty); //**** It throws the exception here

        list = dbQuery
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList<T>();
    }
    return list;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: I cannot answer your problem directly but be aware that using EF in this fashion will cause both the `OrderByDescending()` and the `Take()` clause to perform those operation on the records in memory and not within SQL since you are returning a `List<T>` from your `GetAll()` method.  Meaning, if you have 10,000 records, your current method will send 10,000 records to your application in which you then sort and take 100 of them.  To prevent, you want your `.OrderBy` and `.Take()` statements to apply to the EF context query **Before** you call `ToList()`.

Comment: @Tommy, I see what you mean and I will take care of that. how can I use order by like we all do in SQL before taking everything into memory

Comment: Just to be sure, what you want is `Include`? and not `Where`? Because as you are calling `GetAll` it seems that you want to apply a filter.

Comment: How should I use Include? I dont get it, Include is for eagerloading

Comment: `Include` is for early loading related entities. If what you want is load all entities into memory, this is done when you convert the query to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Expression in EF is expected to be a lambda that retrieves a **property** of an object. In your example

```
d => d.DateToDisplay <= DateTime.Today
```

is a **predicate** - it evaluates to a Boolean value: that's why Include cannot determine which property to "include".

I guess you've confused Include with a LINQ Where clase. Apparently, this should work:

```
_menuRepository.GetAll(d => d.DateToDisplay).OrderByDescending(d=>d.Id).Take(100).ToList();
```

if only type T has property **DateToDisplay**.

Comment: thanks a lot, But It says "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'DBModel.Menu' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'DateToDisplay'."

Comment: @ayilmaz: `GetAll(d => d.DateToDisplay)` isn't needed in your case.

Comment: @ayilmaz that's what I meant by "if only type T has property DateToDisplay". Let me rephrase: what 'Include' does - it 'loads' the contents of the property specified by given Expression (in the sample I've posted it would be DateToDisplay). If your data model (say T) has no public property called 'DateToDisplay', this won't work. However if an entity does not have a particular property, then there is no need to load it. If you described what you're trying to achieve with that GetAll method, we might provide you with a more detailed solution.